# What is the outcome of the events at the end of the game?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

> Did Alfred and Batman really die at the end of the game?

I had this question because after the bomb blast scene someone saves a family from criminals and a shadow of Batman appears.

> Did Batman fake his and Alfred's death?  Will there be a new Batman?

Comment: Modified the title because I think there are too hard spoilers in the title.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a definite answer to this question.  I think this falls under the same territory as the ending to Nolan's TDKR.  It's intentionally ambiguous and you can make of it what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ending to *Arkham Knight* is intentionally vague, and theories abound.

With Batman's identity revealed, Bruce Wayne feels like he needs to take some drastic action to prevent the inevitable fallout.  Does he kill himself and Alfred?  Given that Batman is staunchly anti-murder, I can't believe that's the case.  More than likely he's faked his death in order to go into hiding, much like the end of Nolan's *The Dark Knight Rises.*  Plus, we've already had several death fakes in the Arkham series, so what's one more?

From the post-game cutscene you mention, Gotham still has a bat-themed protector.  It could still be Bruce Wayne, reprising his role as Batman despite his "death."  This could be [Azrael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azrael_(comics)), who is training to be Batman in several of *Arkham Knight's* challenges.  It could also be some other person - Robin, Nightwing, etc.

Until Rocksteady or Warner Bros. decides what's next for the series, we won't know.  I find it 100% likely that there will be more Batman games in this vein at some point in the future...

Comment: Thnx man. U really have good points to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Batman's identity is released to the world and Alfred tells batman to activate the knight fall protocol

Comment: In full ending batman returns to wayne manor and alferd gifts him something as they were entering the wayne manor there is a blast and after that i dont know what happened they are alive or dead